# rmarkdown - grid layout

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

How can one set up a grid layout in `rmarkdown` please?

In the .rmd script below, I have tried having rows, following [this `flexdashboard` example](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/). But it does not work: the charts/tables appear one below the other in the pdf.

**Snippet:**

````
---
title: "Row Orientation"
output: pdf_document
orientation: rows
classoption: landscape
---
Row
-------------------------------------
### Chart 1
```{r}
hist(AirPassengers)
```
Row
-------------------------------------
### Chart 2
```{r}
head(mtcars)
```
### Chart 3
```{r}
hist(AirPassengers)
```
````

What do you think is wrong with this code please?

Comment: try using `gridExtra` packe found here, https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/gridExtra.pdf , to see if you can get what you are looking for out of rMarkdown.

Comment: @sconfluentus Actually you are right that `gridextra`works... but only insofar as what you want to display are graphs ( as far as I know). How about if you have e.g., a table somewhere (I edited my question to reflect this possiblity)? Thx.

Comment: There is an example of using it with  tables on Cran. I think you can make anything into a gridObject

Comment: @sconfluentus Ok, will check that :) and report the findings in here.